# Why does the mysql backup grow if a table is crashed?

Tags: mysql, debian-squeeze, database-backup, server-crashes

I use this backup script on my debian squeeze server to create a backup of all mysqltables:

```
#!/bin/sh

BACKUP_DIR=/var/backups/mysql/
DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

for i in /var/lib/mysql/*/; do
    dbname=`basename "$i"` 
    mysqldump "$dbname" | gzip > $BACKUP_DIR/$dbname.sql.gz
done

# delete old backups older than 1 day
find $BACKUP_DIR -atime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

Now sometimes if a table is "marked as crashed" (MyISAM), this backup creates a huge file, several GB .

How can I prevent that?

I use that in combination with rsnapshot, that backups the BACKUP_DIR again hourly but only incremental. And if there is suh an amok-backupfile it will fill my complete harddrive after several hours.

I helped myself provisionally by adding these lines:

```
# delete backups > 2GB 
find $BACKUP_DIR -size +2000M -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe u should consider modifying your script in order to execute a table check prior to backup. (or schedule a check via cron on regular basis)

[myslqlcheck](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html) is a native tool shipped with mysql distro that can analyze and repair your tables. just have a look at manual page and watch which flags will suit your db most.

Beside your current backup problem it's a good idea to schedule such a task and most important identifying the reasons behind your tables crashes.

Below an usage example: check and repair all databases in your instance

```
mysqlcheck --user=someuser --password=somepassword --all-databases --auto-repair
```